# How to Handle different Versions of TwinCat 3

Tags: twincat

Currenty I use several virtual machines to handle the diferent versions. I have 3:

TC31-FULL-Setup.3.1.4024.10 Visual Studio 2017 or 2019

TC31-Full-Setup.3.1.4022.4 Visual Studio 2015

TC31-Full-Setup.3.1.4018.47 Visual Studio 2013

I have had multiple versions at the same operative system but it brings problems like the version of the visualization manager or some libraries....

About this theme: https://alltwincat.com/2017/06/29/developing-code-for-different-runtimes/

Some tips or experiences are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently written more about how to handle different versions of TwinCAT. You can read more about it here:

https://alltwincat.com/2020/11/02/handling-different-versions-of-twincat/